# Can not reach http api server from external IP

Tags: server, ip, c#

I have a api http server on a pc Ubuntu 17.04. I've forwarded port 2002 on my router to this pc. The matter that I'm successfully able to connect to my server by url with local IP - http://192.168.xxx.xxx:2002/... and get data to my browser.

But when I use an external ip like http://112.69.13.202:2002/..., the result is Not found(Not found) and my server wasn't displaying any client connect to. I've checked port by canyouseeme.org and it returned success.

When I installed that server on window 10 PC, it didn't have that matter. The server I build by C# .net core platform.

p/s: I use httplistener from c#. I also try to disable firewall by command `*sudo ufw disable*`

Thanks.

Comment: Is the command `telnet 112.69.13.202 2002` showing connected ?

Comment: @Rooney yes, it returned connected

Comment: Is 112.69.13.202 the actual IP address, or just one you made up. I'm not showing port 80 or 443 open on that server.

Comment: @barrycarter This ip is a dynamic ip and it changed. When I used wireshark to get frames in my ubuntu PC, i see that I've received some frames. But the HTTP listener response 404. I think the matter is in the HTTPListenner.

Comment: I tried to use http server on python and it worked. I think the matter is in HttpListener .Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

The external IP that you are using should be a static IP. As the IP is dynamic, it will change in a certain period.
So check with your ISP and make sure your external IP is static one.

Comment: I 've checked, this ip is still not changed. This will changed when I reset my router

Comment: I forgot to add one more thing, the ISP may have been using NAT/Firewall which may be blocking incoming connections to your external IP . So it would be better you must have static IP

Comment: But when I installed this server on Window 10 PC, It worked. So I don' think the matter is in router an ISP

Comment: Are you able to access the local URL from another machine in the same local network ?